# Is this system testing or end-to-end testing? How would I do system testing if it's not?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, manual-testing, system-testing

We have a windows desktop client(a branched version from main branch) 2-tier software that uses data source in sql server. I'm supposed to do system testing for this software at work.

The software is a product/order/component catalogue software that contains information about computer models hierarchy with components that are suitable for that models. Each models can also be tracked to orders, and orders can give details about the computer model and specific components that the computer is configured with.

We have three types of users and each users have different access rights. For example, admin can create new users. Users could be viewer and editor. Editor have read&write access. Viewer have only read access.

I'm kinda new to software testing. But I'm thinking since it's system testing. That I should: 
-create users.
-using created editor to create an item.
-using the editor account to create an order containing this item. 
-using a viewer to view the order. 
-using the editor to delele the order. 
-using the viewer to search for the order or component and assert that order is gone but component is still there.
-checking in the database if the order is removed but the component is still there.

Could this be a good start for a system testing for this application?

Also, is there a way or strategy to automate tests somehow? We might have access to QTP.

/JB

Comment: One of the areas would be to check whether privileges of different types of users are really respected, e.g., whether only editor is the one that could read and write.

Comment: What if DB is down and you try to delete same order twice?

Comment: You haven't said whether multiple users can modify DB at the same time? Also, can one user have multiple sessions opened at the same time?

Comment: Checking data integrity: what happens when you try to remove a product from a catalog when there is an order with this product already?

Comment: @dzieciou thanks for the good techniques. But my questions was more like, what is the main focus for system testing? I'm a bit confused since system testing is very similar to end-to-end tests. So would this be system testing?

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from the title of your question at all, so perhaps you should rephrase the title and the question content. Anyway, in my company those terms are used interchangeably, but others may have their own definition, including the person who tasked you with this (you perhaps should ask this person). Note also, that same question has been already answered in this forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378183/difference-between-system-testing-and-end-to-end-testing

Comment: @dzieciou Thanks, I just edited the title to emphasise if it's system testing or end-to-end. It seems like my testing ideas was end-to-end according to the definition in the link you provided.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would test this software will be focusing on different areas:

1. unit testing or library:

   - I am not sure whether you will have access to the code or the developers have done some unit test on the components in the software. In this phase, you can test out the functionality of the components in the software easily (without the interaction of the UI, and most of the database server conditions e.g., lost connection, timeout etc can be mocked easily).
2. User stories or UAT testing:

   - I am not sure you have external customers or not. If not, you can impersonate as one of the three users and try to use the software. The main focus there is to make sure the software is able to solve the problems of the three users in a scenario etc.
3. UI or usability testing:

   - as the name implies, to ensure the button/form/text field etc make sense for the user. You properly will find most of these problems when doing UAT testing.
4. Performance testing:

   - not sure the software will be heavily used or not. Just in case, it needs to support multiple concurrent transactions. You might want to ensure the database is able to handle the load and no duplicate user can be created.

2 & 4 need to be done in a test environment (system testing)
1 & 3 can be done in isolation.